# INSERT trigger to update a field that is NOT NULL in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a situation where I need to merge two product tables into one and need to keep both id fields.  The Id field is the pk and an identity column.  On insert I want to update the prodId to match the Id of the newly inserted row.  This is what I have but I get an error saying that I cannot insert null into ProductId.  What am I doing wrong?

```
ALTER TRIGGER SyncId
    ON Product
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ID INT
    SET @ID = (SELECT ID FROM Inserted)
    UPDATE Product SET
        ProdId = @ID
    WHERE
        Id = @ID    
END
```

Comment: Well, can you insert `NULL` into ProductID? (eg: is there a `NOT NULL` constraint)?

Comment: Yes there is a constraint.  I guess it makes sense that the I can't update the row if it hasn't been inserted yet.  Is there a way to set this with a trigger before it is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an `INSTEAD OF` trigger for the `INSERT`. You would then have to recreate the actual `INSERT` logic. You might need a view of the table for the trigger to sit on though... I don't recall if an `INSERT` within the trigger will work or not and can't test it right now.

Also, your trigger as written will only work if a single row is being updated. You should always write your triggers to be able to handle multiple rows in the `INSERTED` and `DELETED` tables.